# Almost every game crashed on Lineage OS

Tags: custom-roms, rom, lineageos, google-play-games

I've one big problem on my phone. Almost every game crashes on start without any reason. Currently I have only one game which works - Farming simulator 18. Even my game exported from Unity3D isn't working. All apps are working well.

My phone:
Lenovo P70-a
Lineage OS 14.1 (Android 7.1.2)

Log filtered only for `*:F` (Fault errors):
[image: Fault errors]

Does anyone know what to do with this issue?

Comment: Your lineage is Unofficial, maybe try and get Official one.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no official for Lenovo P70. I know that this issue is because of my ROM. But I hope, that it is somehow repairable.

Comment: This should rather be reported to the ROM's forum thread if there is one.

Comment: @AndyYan Where can I find one? XDA dev. didn't helped me (neither they didn't answer me)

Comment: Just posting it to XDA would be enough - don't expect a reply there, no dev is obliged to fix anything.

Comment: @AndyYan that's bad :(